# Dynamically get data from database using Ajax without a refresh interval

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been working with jquery/ajax requests. I have successfully got a ajax request which will retrieve data from a database, the problem is, that i'm constantly serving `window.setInterval()` to refresh this function every x amount of seconds.

How would I change this to keep the ajax request alive, so it updates the html content without having to serve multiple requests to my ajax script.

My code follows:

```
window.setInterval(function()
{
  $(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'Ajax.php'+SearchTerm, dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
        {
        $('#NumberOfVotes').empty();

            for (var i in rows)
            {
                var row = rows[i];          
                var QuestionID = row[0];
                var Votes = row[1];
                $('#NumberOfVotes')
                .append(Votes);
            } 
        } 
    });       
  });
}, 500);
```

Comment: setInterval is the right way to do this. If you want an asynchronous server you should try [node.js](http://nodejs.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of this depends on how your server would be able to update it's content dynamically.  That said, what you are looking for is websockets.  Websockets are designed to replace the long-polling paradigm.

EDIT: Since you use mainly php for your server technology, look at Ratchet.  I've heard good things about it http://socketo.me/

Here is an excellent article on using websockets with HTML
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

.NET has a great socket library in SignalR
http://signalr.net/

There is a myriad of php documentation on sockets out there
http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Comment: A nice thing with SignalR is that it falls back to long-polling and similar techniques for older browsers that lack native support for web sockets.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson Yes, amongst other things.  The SignalR library is so revolutionary that Scott Hansleman and company have now included it as part of a standard web library for .NET.  It's incredibly powerful

Comment: Should have specified that I am mainly using PHP

Comment: @user2146021 No worries.  I've updated my answer with an excellent PHP websocket library that I've heard recommended quite often and retagged your question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: The main issue with websockets is that they are still not well supported by some browsers

Comment: @Claw True, which is why SignalR is such a gem.  If the browser does not support websockets it automatically falls back to long-polling, so there's only gain.  It may take the PHP world a bit to catch up to SignalR, but there are plenty of excellent ways to fill the gaps

Answer (score 0):

look into using web sockets - you could send the client a message anytime they need to go an look for new data - that way your not making any unnecessary requests. Try checking out pubnub -service is cheap and could handle everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need something server side that keeps the request alive until it has something to return. This is usually called "Comet", "Long-polling" or "Push".

The principle is :

1. You send a request client-side via AJAX
2. Your server receives the request, and doesn't return a response yet. It sleeps/waits until it has something to return
3. A new entry in your database ! Your server now has something to return : it returns some JSON data for the waiting request
4. Your receive the response server side, display what you have to display, and go back to step 1 sending another request.

Now, the implementation server side will depend on the language/framework you are using.

---

Edit :

Some examples using PHP :

[Comet and PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)

[Simple Comet Implementation Using PHP and jQuery](http://webscepter.com/simple-comet-implementation-using-php-and-jquery/)

Comment: I edited my answer adding examples of PHP Comet implementations. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set `xhr.multipart = true` and modify server code. see [Multipart Responses Example Code](http://newtonapples.com/ajax-program-multipart-responses-code/). Alternative way is to use websockets as mentioned